# Defining While Loop Functions With a List Containing Digits

Tags: python, function

Define a function named add_from_one_again(st) which receives a  list containing digits only (at least one digit, and all digits >0, no need to validate)   and returns a number as illustrated by the following examples

When the list is 
[5,2,3]
the resulting number should be:
(1+2+3+4+5)  + (1+2)  + (1+2+3)   =  24

When the list is 
[3,2,5]
the resulting number should be:
(1+2+3) + (1+2) + (1+2+3+4+5) = 24

When the list is
[4,2,2]
the resulting number should be:
(1+2+3+4) + (1+2) + (1+2) = 16

Comment: Thanks for keeping us up to date with your homework. Do you have a question? Have you tried anything?

Comment: `sum([n * (n + 1) / 2 for n in list])`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited as per requirements. Let know if it works:-

```
def add_from_one_again(st):
    return sum([int(i*(i+1)/2) for i in st])

print(add_from_one_again([16,12,89]))
```

Comment: Your code is not very efficient for large values in the list. You should apply Gauss' formula instead of nested loops.

Comment: Well written off. ;) Try both versions for `add_from_one_again(range(10000))`. You will see a difference.

Comment: I checked this and noticed the difference

Comment: Hey @Abhijeetk431 ! Thanks for your reply. I just tried it out and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help. I had no idea I had to include (i+1).

Answer (score -2):

Use this :

```
def add_from_one_again(st):
    collect_sum = 0
    for i in st:
        collect_sum += sum(range(i))
    return collect_sum
```

Comment: Not downvoter, but... why? Why would you answer a "question" that's clearly an assignment presented as a demand for code?

Comment: I'm obviously asking this question because I've tried multiple times and I can't seem to find the answer. Do you enjoy commenting things like this on other people's questions?

Comment: @montblanc what I enjoy doing is trying to preserve the best resource for programming solutions. a) your question shows no effort _at all_ (so it's not obvious that you did anything to solve this) and b) is useless for helping people in future. I'm not the only person that found this "question" (you didn't even ask a question) to be outside of the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your code is not very efficient for large values in the list. You should apply Gauss' formula instead of nested loops.

Comment: @roganjosh How do you know I made no effort just by looking at my post? Just because I didn't include all of my attempts, doesn't mean I didn't try to solve this question. I've been stuck on this question for hours and I made an account just so I could get help. I've never done this before. You weren't the only person to find this question outside the scope of Stack Overflow but you seem to be the only one committed enough to actually leave comments like these.

Comment: @montblanc I could have just downvoted, voted to close and moved on in silence. Instead, I'm going to point you to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); if you have several badly-received questions then you will be banned from asking. This is not a dig at you, there are _a lot_ of people that just dump homework here and demand an answer without any effort. Re-read your post as though you're an outsider - it's just a series of demands from us.#

Comment: Man, I answer questions which I can answer. Now it's started to affect my reputation.

Comment: Montblanc - Put yourself in our place.  You cannot expect a group of total strangers to understand your level of Python knowledge, or figure out what part of the assignment is giving you problems and where you need help.  You need to show us what you've tried so far so we can point to what is wrong with it.  roganjosh assumes you've done nothing because you've shown us nothing.  You also should read the site's guidelines before posting for the first time.

Comment: @pissall as I said, I'm not the downvoter, but answering these kind of questions will not be received well by some in the community.

Comment: @roganjosh I see where you're coming from, but the way you came out was not necessary at all. No one "demands" you to answer these questions. Some people like the ones who commented to help me out actually enjoy answering these questions on their spare time. It doesn't affect anyone negatively.

Comment: @montblanc I answer questions in my spare time too; I enjoy it and learn a lot from it, you can see the questions I've answered. I've also asked some terrible questions that got closed too. Other than the slightly sarcastic comment under your initial post, I've only been objective. I can understand why you would dislike my comments but I've only been direct about the issue, this isn't social media where sentiment is dressed-up. Don't take it personally :)